# Time format ios "2014-04-28T01:03:21.827753"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Any body knows about `2014-04-28T01:03:21.827753` like format,
 i have the methods to handle `2014-04-28T01:03:21` format but i didn't heard about like formats any one help me , that would be highly thank-full.

**Here is my code:-**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.??????"];// ? what i need to use please anyone route me in right way
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeStamp];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would appear to be a variation of [RFC 3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt)/[ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). See Apple's [Technical Q&A QA1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html) for guidance about this format (making special note of the timezone and locale).

Note, your string doesn't specify the timezone, but it's generally assumed to be Zulu (i.e. UTC/GMT), though you should confirm this with whomever generated this time string. Also, don't forget to specify the locale for your formatter, in case the user's calendar is not in the standard Gregorian format.

```
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.locale = enUSPOSIXLocale;
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS";
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:timeStamp];
```

Answer (score 4):

As per the [Unicode Locale Data Markup Language](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) Use this format:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSS"];
```

Use as many "S" to show as many decimal point values you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS"];
```

'S' is for millisecond. There are 1000 (0 to 999) milliseconds in a second.

Comment: DeepK more suitable and correct answer is Rob's one so i changed sorry

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'T' HH:mm:ss.SS"];
```

[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'string you want' HH:mm:ss.SS"];

'S' is for millisecond.There are 1000 (0 to 999) milliseconds in a second.